# How can I tell what syntax and indentation rules Vim is using on a particular line?

Tags: vim, syntax, indentation

For better or worse, PHP code often includes both HTML and Javascript. Getting Vim to indent it all correctly can be tricky.

My `.vimrc` specifies that a tab should always be two spaces:

```
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

[This indent file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=604) does a good job with indenting mixed PHP and HTML and uses 2 spaces for both, but for some reason, it indents embedded Javascript with 4 spaces. The code snippet below gets auto-indented as shown.

```
<?PHP
  if (false) {
    $foo = 'foo';
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function(){
          if (false) {

              // Four spaces!?
              var foo = 'foo';
          }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

If I create a separate javascript file, it indents as it should, like so:

```
if (false) {
  var foo = 'foo';
}
```

I'm not sure why Vim indents the Javascript in the first example as it does. **Is there a way to ask Vim "what syntax or indentation are you using on this specific line?"**

Comment: That sounds right. The convention in Javascript is to use 4 spaces. Check your Javascript syntax file. It may or may not be delegating it to that.

Comment: @digitxp - I don't have a `/syntax/javascript.vim` currently. I do have a `indent/javascript`, but that just decides when to indent or unindent, not how many spaces to use for an indent. And, as I said, a separate JS file gets indented with my default of two spaces.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I suspect that BOTH the PHP and HTML rules are being applied.

Answer (score 3):

To find out the syntax in use, you want to know the value of the variable b:current_syntax.  Type the following Ex. command

```
:echo b:current_syntax
```

*b:current_syntax* says what syntax vim loaded for the file.  If you set the syntax manually, such as with the command

```
:ownsyntax cpp
```

which sets the syntax to c++ syntax, then you want to know the value of *w:current_syntax*.  *w:current_syntax* doesn't exist until you set it, and you cannot change *b:current_syntax* of a loaded file.

Look at the *current_syntax* entry in *help* for more information.